# Turn on admin in config.js to view server stats

Tags: mongodb, docker, server

After pulling run this commands

```
"docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name mongodb --net mongo-network mongo "
```

for mongodb and this

```
"docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password --net mongo-network --name mongo-express -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb mongo-express"
```

for mongo express after opening the port in my localhost:8081 on server side it is showing that "Turn on admin in config.js to view server stats!" i'm kind of stuck here

Comment: What is the error? What do you expect in response? Please be more specific in your problem description.

Comment: At first I pull the mongodb and mongoexpress image than run it ., by using the following commands . at the localhost:8081 where it suppose to show the server status it's showing that "turn on admin in config.js to view server stats".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem. So i went and checked mongo-express-docker Github issue page. Someone raised a question there.

Apparently, mongo-express in docker latest release is 1.0.0-alpha, doesn't have server status, but 0.54.0 had it.

Try: `docker pull mongo-express:0.54.0`

And then remember to use `mongo-express:0.54.0` for whatever you're doing later.

Comment: command should be "docker pull mongo-express:0.54.0", not mongodb

Comment: Would have been helpful to [link the issue](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/issues/809) to see if it's been resolved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a tag `--restart always`. It's working fine for me.

```bash
docker network create mongo-network

docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name mongodb --net mongo-network --restart always mongo

docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password --net mongo-network --name mongo-express -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb --restart always mongo-express
```